# Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, algolia

Don't know why it isn't working. The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086459/error-inflating-class-de-hdodenhof-circleimageview-circleimageview-in-android-ve) doesn't apply to me, since my dimensions are already in `dp`.

Here is my activity

**hits_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:algolia="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/user_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#c42f92"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    algolia:attribute='@{"image"}'/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    algolia:attribute='@{"username"}'
    algolia:highlighted='@{true}'/>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: @Zoe Oh okay, I didn't know.

Comment: Have you added Gradle dependency of the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line make your app crash

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

From [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) github.

> **Limitations**
>
> The ScaleType is always CENTER_CROP and you'll get an exception if you
>   try to change it. This is (currently) by design as it's perfectly fine
>   for profile images.

In logcat you will see this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScaleType FIT_CENTER not supported.
```

**Solution:** Remove `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` from the layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're incorrectly adding a tag as a View xml. This is wrong:

```
<!-- Below line is in a wrong place and wrong tag. -->
<layout xmlns:algolia="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   ...
</LinearLayout>
```

it should be:

```
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:algolia="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   ...

</LinearLayout>
```